# Android AsyncTask with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` that populates my `listview` with rows.  When the row content is being coded, I need to make a call to download Facebook profile images. I'm executing an `AsyncTask` inside the `ArrayAdapter` but I don't know how to actually put the image downloaded into the ArrayAdpter row's imageview.

Do I do this on the onPostExecute? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using Universal Image Loader for this purpose? It works flawlessly in ListView.

Comment: I have never heard  of this.  Can you show me an article or tutorial that talks about this?  It will work in an ArrayAdapter load of ListView, correct?

Comment: post your adapter and asynctask code

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader and https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.